# Почему одеколон называют тройным?

Tags: названия

Всегда было интересно, почему знаменитый одеколон называют тройным? Это что, как "два (точнее, три) в одном"?)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в нём изначально было лишь три душистых компонента: бергамот, лимон и нероли. Сейчас состав может варьироваться в зависимости от производителя, но основа по прежнему они.